# Variance partitioning and longitudinal changes in correlation with binary data

Tags: mixed-model, binary-data

I am analysing data on 300,000 pupils in 175 schools with a logistic linear mixed effects model (random intercepts). Each pupil occurs exactly once and the data spans 6 years.

1. How do I partition variance between the school and pupil levels, in a similar way to the VPC/ICC for continuous outcomes ? I have seen [this](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/research/pvmm.pdf) article which proposes 4 methods, of which A and B appear interesting to me, but I would like to know what advantages/drawbacks there could be in using either of these, and of course if there are any other ways to do it.
2. How can I compare the school-level residual variance from year to year (or any other time period) ? So far I have done this by dividing the data by year and running the model against each year of data but I think this is flawed because: i) there is no obvious reason why I should be split by *year*; and ii) since the fixed effects estimates are different for each year, comparing the random effects year by year may not make sense (this is just my intuition it would be great if someone could explain this more formally, if it is correct).

NOTE: I re-wrote this question after a [discussion in meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1206/how-can-i-improve-my-question) with whuber and Macro

Comment: I think this is a major improvement. The question is now very clear. Right now I don't have time to give a well-organized response but I'll post an answer later.

Comment: Logistic mixed effects models seems like an extremely advanced topic for high school. Are they part of your high school syllabus or are you studying independently?

Comment: @mark999 I am studying independently. Actually I am trying to prove my brother wrong who said _"there is no way you could understand this"_ . He is doing a degree in statistics so I have access to all his books etc. (when he is being nice).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $y_{ij}, {\boldsymbol x}_{ij}$ denote the response and predictor vector (respectively) of student $i$ in school $j$.

**(1)** For binary data, I think the standard way to do variance decompositions analogous to those done for continuous data is what the authors call **Method D** (I'll comment on the other methods below) in your link - envisioning the binary data as arising from a underlying continuous variable that is governed by a linear model and decompose the variance on that latent scale. The reason is that logistic models (and other GLMs) naturally arises this way--

To see this, define  $y^{\star}_{ij}$ such that it is governed by a linear mixed model:

$$ y^{\star}_{ij} = \alpha + {\boldsymbol x}_{ij} {\boldsymbol \beta} + \eta_j + \varepsilon_{ij} $$

where $\alpha,\beta$ are regression coefficients, $\eta_j \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ is the school level random effect and $\varepsilon_{ij}$ is the residual variance term and has a standard [logistic distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution). Now let

$$
y_{ij} = 
\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if} \ \ \ y^{\star}_{ij}≥0\\
\\
0 &\text{if} \ \ \ y^{\star}_{ij}<0
\end{cases}
$$

let $p_{ij} = P(y_{ij} = 1|{\boldsymbol x}_{ij},\eta_j)$ now, simply using the logistic CDF we have

$$p_{ij} = 1-P(y^{\star}_{ij}<0|{\boldsymbol x}_{ij},\eta_j) = \frac{ \exp \{-(\alpha + {\boldsymbol x}_{ij} {\boldsymbol \beta} + \eta_j) \} }{1+ \exp \{-(\alpha + {\boldsymbol x}_{ij} {\boldsymbol \beta} + \eta_j) \}}$$

now taking the [logit transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit) of both sides, you have

$$ \log \left( \frac{ p_{ij} }{1 - p_{ij}} \right) = \alpha + {\boldsymbol x}_{ij} {\boldsymbol \beta} + \eta_j $$

which is exactly the logistic mixed effects model. So, the logistic model is equivalent to the latent variable model specified above. One important note:

- The scale of $\varepsilon_{ij}$ is not identified since, if you were to scale it down but a constant $s$, it would simply change the above to

$$ \frac{ \exp \{-(\alpha + {\boldsymbol x}_{ij} {\boldsymbol \beta} + \eta_j)/s \} }{1+ \exp \{-(\alpha + {\boldsymbol x}_{ij} {\boldsymbol \beta} + \eta_j)/s \}}$$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ $therefore the coefficients and random effects would simply be scaled up by the
$\ \ \ \ \ \ $ corresponding amount. So, $s=1$ is used, which implies ${\rm var}(\varepsilon_{ij}) = \pi^2/3$.

Now, if you use this model and then the quantity

$$ \frac{ \hat{\sigma}^{2}_{\eta} }{\hat{\sigma}^{2}_{\eta} + \pi^2/3 } $$

estimates the intraclass correlation of the **underlying latent variables**. Another important note:

- If $\varepsilon_{ij}$ is specified as, instead, having a standard normal distribution, then you have the mixed effects [probit model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probit_model). In that case $$ \frac{ \hat{\sigma}^{2}_{\eta} }{\hat{\sigma}^{2}_{\eta} + 1 } $$ estimates the *[tetrachoric correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychoric_correlation)* between two randomly selected pupils in the same school, which were shown by Pearson (around 1900 I think) to be statistically identified when the underlying continuous data was normally distributed (this work actually showed these correlations were identified beyond the binary case to the multiple category case, where these correlations are termed [*polychoric correlations*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polychoric_correlation)). **For this reason, it may be preferable (and would be my recommenation) to use a probit model when the primary interest is in estimating the (tetrachoric) intraclass correlation of binary data.**

Regarding the other methods mentioned in the paper you linked:

- **(A)** I've never seen the linearization method, but one drawback I can see is that there's no indication of the approximation error incurred by this. In addition, if you're going to linearize the model (through a potentially crude approximation), why not just use a linear model in the first place (e.g. option **(C)**, which I'll get to in a minute)? It would also be more complicated to present since the ICC would depend on ${\boldsymbol x}_{ij}$.
- **(B)** The simulation method is intuitively appealing to a statistician since it would give you an estimated variance decomposition on the original scale of the data but, depending on the audience, it may (i) be complicated to describe this in your "methods" section and (ii) may turn off a reviewer who was looking for something "more standard"
- **(C)** Pretending the data is continuous is probably not a great idea, although it won't perform terribly if most of the probabilities are not too close to 0 or 1. But, doing this would almost certainly raise a red flag to a reviewer so I'd stay away.

Now finally,

**(2)** If the fixed effects are very different across years, then you're right to think that it could be difficult to compare the random effect variances across years, since they are potentially on different scales (this is related to the non-identifiability of scaling issue mentioned above).

If you want to keep the fixed effects over time (however, if you see them changing a lot over time, you may not want to do that) but look at the change in the random effect variance, you can explore this effect using some random slopes and dummy variables. For example, if you wanted to see if the ICCs were different in different years, you culd let $I_k = 1$ if the observation was made in year $k$ and 0 otherwise and then model your linear predictor as

$$\alpha + {\boldsymbol x}_{ij} {\boldsymbol \beta} + \eta_{1j} I_1 + \eta_{2j} I_2 + 
\eta_{3j} I_3 + \eta_{4j} I_4 + \eta_{5j} I_5+ \eta_{6j} I_6$$

this will give you a different ICCs each year but the same fixed effects. It may be tempting to just use a random slope in time, making your linear predictor

$$\alpha + {\boldsymbol x}_{ij} {\boldsymbol \beta} + \eta_{1} + \eta_{2} t $$

but I don't recommend this, since that will only allow your associations to *increase* over time, not *decrease*.

Comment: Please would you give me your comment to address the point in the linked article about this variance partitioning technique that says _"This approach may be reasonable where the (0, 1) response is, say, derived from a truncation of an underlying continuum such as a pass/fail response based upon a continuous mark scale, but would seem to have less justification when the response is truly discrete, such as mortality or voting"_. In my case I am dealing with the incidence of bullying, which falls into the latter category, I think...

Comment: @JoeKing, I would say that logistic/probit (and similar) regression models already assume that the data are generated from an underlying continuum, since the model can be shown to be equivalent to that. Therefore, if one is even using such models, then they must find that assumption to be defensible :)

Comment: @JoeKing, _if_ you consider this answer definitive please consider accepting :)

Comment: I will indeed. At the moment I'm a bit uncertain about a few points and I'd like to come back to you after I've had a little time (couple of days) to read around a little, and look at the data some more, if you don't mind ?

Comment: @JoeKing Of course - some new members are unaware, so I thought I'd point that out - it wasn't meant to place pressure you at all

Comment: Please can you explain the assertion that $V(y_{ij}) > p_{ij}(1-p_{ij})$ is implied by method A ?

Comment: @JoeKing, If you look at the approximation, you will see the term $p_{ij}(1-p_{ij})$ **plus** another non-negative term (if I remember correctly), which was my basis for saying that.

Comment: Thanks :) I think you are referring to _"so that for a given value of $x_1$ we have ${\rm var}(y_{ij} | x_{1ij})=... +\pi_{ij}(1-\pi_{ij})$"_ but that's the conditional distribution - does that make any difference ?

Comment: @JoeKing, I think you may be right and that I've mixed up terms. I'll  modify my answer. I still think that this approach isn't particularly appealing since there's no indication of the approximation error incurred and if you're going to linearize the model, why not use a linear model in the first place? There's also the pesky fact that your ICC then depends on $x$ :)

Comment: Thanks again. I think I understand that point. The main concern I have with the method you described first is still what I mentioned in my first comment. I was able to look at the book "Multilevel Statistical Models" by H Goldstein 2009 edition today , which I have been informed is a "standard reference". I was a bit surprised to find that the paper I linked to in my OP appears almost verbatim in the book, with the passage I mentioned in my comment unaltered. I appreciate what you said in your reply to my comment, but I still have an uneasy feeling about it....[cont]

Comment: [cont].... I can see what you mean about "logistic/probit (and similar) regression models already assume that the data are generated from an underlying continuum, since the model can be shown to be equivalent to that" but does that mean that such models should not be used if there is a "truly discrete" outcome ?

Comment: The paper appears almost verbatim because they are written by the same author :) I'm not sure what you mean by "truly discrete". It seems any time you have a binary outcome, you can imagine that "not all 1s are created equal" in that some are "closer" to being a 0 than others. I've just given you my take on what you should do - if there is dogma in your field as to what method is "best" then you may need to adhere to it in order to get published. From my experience, the latent variable approach is most common and is intuitively appealing, due to its connection with the underlying model

Comment: Thanks again. I'm not trying to be argumentative, just trying to understand. Sorry if you think I am being awkward. I don't have a field (yet) - I'm just learning about statistics. I said "truly discrete" because that's the wording that appears in the paper and the book. So if they mean that this method should not be used in the case of (their examples) death or voting, then by extension, a logistic regression model shouldn't be used anyway for these outcomes. Am I on the wrong tracks ?

Comment: No, these are good questions, no need to feel self conscious about it. I would say that voting and death are not "truly discrete". Some living people are far closer to death than others. Some people who vote democratic are far closer to center than others. I'd argue you can make similar statements about any binary variable. Logistic regression (and the like) is a useful and powerful tool that can and should be used for many problems involving discrete data.

Comment: may I ask if it is valid to construct a confidence interval for $ \frac{ \hat{\sigma}^{2}_{\eta} }{\hat{\sigma}^{2}_{\eta} + \pi^2/3 } $ by using the end points of a confidence interval for ${\sigma}^{2}_{\eta}$ ?

Comment: @JoeKing, since this is a monotonic transformation, yes, I do this this is a valid thing to do. Although, I don't recall `lme4` giving confidence intervals for the random effect variances - where are you getting them from?

Comment: Thanks once again. I was obtaining the confidence intervals by bootstrapping, although I have run into some problems with that (not sure how to construct the samples to respect the hierarchy in the data ?). As a work-around I have used `MCMCglmm` which produces CIs by default (the Bayesian kind, I suppose), but I would still like to compare with lme4 if possible.